# Scale background image on container hover

Tags: html, css

I have a background image with a background color overlay that I'm trying to scale using `transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);` when I hover on its container.

Even though the code appears in the inspector, it is not taking effect.

This is the CSS that is supposed to scale the background image whenever I hover over the `item` container

```
.item:hover .img-container {
    transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
    opacity: .2;
}
```

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/xaw3vcL1/

HTML

```
<article class="item" style="background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/235470/pexels-photo-235470.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb') center center / cover;">
  <div class="item-content">
    <a href="#" class="img-container"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    Title here
  </div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
.item {
    height: 450px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item:before {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 68.17%;
}

.item-content {
    position: absolute!important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img-container {
    webkit-background-size: cover!important;
    -moz-background-size: cover!important;
    -o-background-size: cover!important;
    background-size: cover!important;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -2px;
    right: -2px;
    bottom: -1px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.img-container:after {
    opacity: .5;
    background: #26D0CE;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,#1A2980 0,#26D0CE 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left bottom,right top,color-stop(0,#1A2980),color-stop(100%,#26D0CE));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,#1A2980 0,#26D0CE 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,#1A2980 0,#26D0CE 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,#1A2980 0,#26D0CE 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,#1A2980 0,#26D0CE 100%);
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .35s ease;
    -o-transition: all .35s ease;
    transition: all .35s ease;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.item:hover .img-container {
    transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
    opacity: .2;
}

.content-container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it doesn't work because the background-image is not set to the `img-container` but to the `article.item` .

you should put the background-image to the right container if you want your code to work.

and, remove `opacity:.2` from `.item:hover .img-container` and add `.item:hover .img-container:after {opacity:.2}`

see snippet or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xaw3vcL1/2/)

```css
.item {
    height: 450px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item:before {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 68.17%;
}

.item-content {
    position: absolute!important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img-container {
    webkit-background-size: cover!important;
    -moz-background-size: cover!important;
    -o-background-size: cover!important;
    background-size: cover!important;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -2px;
    right: -2px;
    bottom: -1px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.img-container:after {
    opacity: .5;
    background: #26D0CE;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,#1A2980 0,#26D0CE 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left bottom,right top,color-stop(0,#1A2980),color-stop(100%,#26D0CE));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,#1A2980 0,#26D0CE 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,#1A2980 0,#26D0CE 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,#1A2980 0,#26D0CE 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,#1A2980 0,#26D0CE 100%);
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .35s ease;
    -o-transition: all .35s ease;
    transition: all .35s ease;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.item:hover .img-container {
    transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
}
.item:hover .img-container:after {
 opacity:.2
}

.content-container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<article class="item" >
  <div class="item-content">
    <a href="#" class="img-container" style="background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/235470/pexels-photo-235470.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb') center center / cover;"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    Title here
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. But if you don't mind me asking, why am I getting a white background when I hover over it now instead of the colors I've chosen?

Comment: the white background is because of the opacity:0.2 on HOVER and the background beneath the `item` is grey/white ( the default body background ) . AND because the `:after` is set to the same item you give opacity:0.2 , it also gets that style. so set the `:after` to the `item` instead of `img-container ` see here https://jsfiddle.net/xaw3vcL1/3/

Comment: This adds another problem, I want to have the background image appear properly instead of having a white background obscuring it even further. Like my original code, when you hover over it the image becomes clearer.

Comment: hmm. if i understand right, you want something like this ?  https://jsfiddle.net/xaw3vcL1/4/ removeing opacity:.2 from `..item:hover .img-container` and adding it to ` .item:hover .img-container:after {
 opacity:.2
}` instead

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much.

Comment: edited my answer with the final solution. glad i could help. cheers ! :D

Answer (score -1):

add this class to your css

```
article:hover{transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
-moz-transform: scale3d(1.1,1.1,1);
opacity:0.2;}
```